# How can I test Rails Routes with Minitest?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, minitest

I'm trying to use Minitest for an existing Rails app (3.2), but not having any luck running routing tests. I've tried rspec syntax (should route_to) and TestUnit syntax (assert_routing) but no luck.

Any advice on getting this to work? Specific modules I need to include, etc?

thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you are using [minitest-rails](https://github.com/blowmage/minitest-rails) you can create route tests by placing the following in `test/routes/homepage_test.rb`:

```
require "minitest_helper"

class HomepageRouteTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  def test_homepage
    assert_routing "/", :controller => "home", :action => "index"
  end
end
```

Alternatively, you can use the Minitest Spec DSL:

```
require "minitest_helper"

describe "Homepage Route Acceptance Test" do
  it "resolves the homepage" do
    assert_routing "/", :controller => "home", :action => "index"
  end
end
```

You can run these tests with the following rake task:

```
rake minitest:routes
```

Comment: I am getting the error undefined method `assert_routing' for #<#<Class:0x007fc6a30d6c60>:0x007fc6a4f7bc60> when using assert_routing. Is there a step that I need to modify in the minitest_helper file to get this to work?

Comment: cr45: You either need to make sure your test class inherits from `MiniTest::Rails::ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest`, or if you are using the spec DSL the top-level describe needs to end in "Integration Test" or "Acceptance Test".

Comment: @blowmage is it still useful to write routing tests like this w/ Rails 4.1 and MiniTest? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24937110/is-it-still-advisable-to-test-routes-in-rails-4-with-minitest

Comment: @pdobb I never claimed it was useful. It's _possible_. I suppose if you have an external dependency on specific routes existing then it's worth writing these tests. It just depends on what your needs are.

Answer (score 3):

@blowmage's answer helped me but it looks like the syntax has changed a bit.

With Rails 4:

```
require "test_helper"

class HomepageRouteTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  def test_messages
    assert_generates '/messages', :controller => "messages", :action => "index"
  end
end
```

Comment: There are three assertions that Rails gives you for checking routes: [assert_routing](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Assertions/RoutingAssertions.html#method-i-assert_routing), [assert_recognizes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Assertions/RoutingAssertions.html#method-i-assert_recognizes), and [assert_generates](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Assertions/RoutingAssertions.html#method-i-assert_generates). Use the assertion that best matches what you are trying to verify.